# filter the ui grid value based on the row check box is selected

Tags: ui-grid, angular1.6

This is the ui grid code( minimal)

//js file

```
vm.gridOptions1 = {
      enableColumnResizing: true,
      enableAutoResizing: false,

 columnDefs: [


        {
          field: 'createdDate',
          displayName: 'Created Date',
          type: 'date',
          cellFilter: 'date:"dd-MM-yyyy"',
          enableHiding: false, headerTooltip: 'Created Date'
        },{
          name: 'Refer',
          displayName: 'Refer', enableSorting: false, headerTooltip: 'Refer',
          cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.isReferred" />'
        }

]});
```

On click of this byutton I need to filter, get only rows which check box is selected(isReferred = true)
//html file

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary-joli " ng-click="srchctrl.send">Send</button>
```

This is the file trying to get the filtered list based on the redeffered check box value, but its not working.
//JS file

```
 vm.send = function () {
      if (vm.gridApi.selection.data != null && vm.gridApi.selection.data != undefined) {
         vm.referredList = filterFilter(vm.gridApi.selection.data, {
          isReferred: true
        });
        console.log("referredList :"+JSON.stringify(referredList));
      }
    };
```

How can I get all the value ticked. I don't want to invoke method on each click event on check box.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is by using the gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor function. I have adapted a Plunker to show what I mean:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lyXcb90yQ0ErUJnSH7yF

Apps.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, uiGridConstants) {

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'col1', displayName: 'Column 1', width: 175},
      {field: 'col2', displayName: 'isReferred', width: '*'}
    ],
    data: [
      { col1: "Hello 1",col2: true},
      { col1: "Hello 2", col2: false},
      { col1: "Hello 3", col2: true},
      { col1: "Hello 4", col2: false},
      { col1: "Hello 5", col2: true}
    ],
    enableFiltering: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
    };

  $scope.Filter = Filter;
  $scope.ShowAll = ShowAll;

  function ShowAll() {
    $scope.gridApi.grid.removeRowsProcessor(myFilter);
    $scope.gridApi.core.queueGridRefresh();
  }

  function Filter() {
    $scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor(myFilter, 150);
    $scope.gridApi.core.queueGridRefresh();
  }

  function myFilter(renderableRows) {
    renderableRows.forEach( function(row) {
      row.visible = row.entity.col2;
    });
    return renderableRows;
  }
}]);
```

Clicking the *Filter* button will register the *myFilter* RowsProcessor, which will iterate through all rows to alter the visible attribute. 
Clicking the *ShowAll* button will remove the RowsProcessor, thus showing all previously hidden rows again.

Whenever an *isReferred* value changes, the filter will cause the grid to automatically update this change.